# Template rendering error after website deploy

Tags: django, web-deployment, webdeploy

my website is about eccommerce activity. As I have deployed the site I am getting several errors. For example I can enter to log in or register user , I got errors like customuser does not exist. But I clearly have a models like below and it was working fine before deploying.

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_merchant = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Another significant error I got in my customer home file template which says:

```
relation "projectapp_product" does not exist
```

The error occuring in store.html:

```
{% extends 'customertemplates/main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<div class="row">
    {% for product in products %}
     <div class="col-lg-4">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="{{product.imageURL}}">
        <div class="box-element product">
            <h6><strong>{{product.product_name}}</strong></h6>
            <h4 style="display: inline-block;"><strong>${{product.discount_price}}</strong></h4>
            <hr>

            <button data-product="{{product.id}}" data-action="add" class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-btn update-cart"><i class='fa fa-shopping-cart yellow-color'></i> Add to Cart</button>
            {% if user.is_authenticated and user.is_customer %}
            <button style="width:110px" class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-btn add-wishlist" data-product="{{product.id}}" data-action="add"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Wishlist</button>
            {% endif %}
            
            <a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="{% url 'product_details' product.pk %}"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</a>
            

        </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

store.views.py:

```
def store(request):
data = cartData(request)

cartItems = data['cartItems']
order = data['order']
items = data['items']

products = Product.objects.all()
context = {'products':products, 'cartItems':cartItems}
return render(request, 'customertemplates/store.html', context)
```

and the model is:

```
class Product(models.Model):
id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
url_slug=models.CharField(max_length=255)
subcategories_id=models.ForeignKey(SubCategories,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
product_name=models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
brand=models.CharField(max_length=255)
max_price=models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
discount_price=models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
product_description=models.TextField()
product_long_description=models.TextField()
in_stock_total=models.IntegerField(default=1)
digital = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True, blank=True)
image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
def __str__(self):
    return self.product_name

@property
def imageURL(self):
    try:
        url = self.image.url
    except:
        url = ''
    return url
```

Comment: The issue is not in the code here its in the compatibility of the database with the server

Comment: How can I solve it?

Comment: By googling around I guess. Once I accidentally included my db in the gitignorefile. Once I encountered a simmilar issue after not reasearching databases enaugh to know the default one will work. My point is the issue could be a thousand things and I have virtually no data helping me help you so I recommend finding a tutorial.

Comment: ok. thanks. I am trying..

Comment: No worries that's usually what happens when you start out. It gets easier once you learn to navigate the documentations.